# Combine datatables with specific conditions

Tags: c#, linq, loops, datatable

UPDATED: Forgot to mention, the table may contain more than one type of itemcode

I've got a problem for datatable. There're total 14 items with same itemcode. And now there're 2 tables come from different source. One is grouped by itemcode and sum up the quantity, when count equals to 10, go to next row, and each row contains specific information such as shipment and remarks. Another table contains more detail information.

Source1: Grouped table

```
ItemCode|TotalQty|Shipment|Remarks|Line
=========================================
ITEM01  |  1000  |  S001  |  R001 |   1    <==10 items here
ITEM01  |  400   |  S002  |  R002 |   2    <==4 items here
```

Source2: Detail table (14 items & rows)

```
RefNo|ItemCode|Quantity|Weight|From
=======================================
R001 | ITEM01 |  100   | 50   | US
R002 | ITEM01 |  100   | 50   | US
R003 | ITEM01 |  100   | 50   | US
  .  |   .    |   .    |  .   |  .
  .  |   .    |   .    |  .   |  .
R013 | ITEM01 |  100   | 50   | US
R014 | ITEM01 |  100   | 50   | US
```

I would like to combine source1 and source2 and get the result as below

```
Shipment|Line|Remarks|ItemCode|TotalQty|RefNo|Quantity|Weight|From
===================================================================
  S001  | 1  | R001  | ITEM01 |  1000  | R001|  100   |  50  | US   \\1
  S001  | 1  | R001  | ITEM01 |  1000  | R002|  100   |  50  | US   \\2
  S001  | 1  | R001  | ITEM01 |  1000  | R003|  100   |  50  | US   \\3
  S001  | 1  | R001  | ITEM01 |  1000  | R004|  100   |  50  | US   \\4
  S001  | 1  | R001  | ITEM01 |  1000  | R005|  100   |  50  | US   \\5
  S001  | 1  | R001  | ITEM01 |  1000  | R006|  100   |  50  | US   \\6
  S001  | 1  | R001  | ITEM01 |  1000  | R007|  100   |  50  | US   \\7
  S001  | 1  | R001  | ITEM01 |  1000  | R008|  100   |  50  | US   \\8
  S001  | 1  | R001  | ITEM01 |  1000  | R009|  100   |  50  | US   \\9
  S001  | 1  | R001  | ITEM01 |  1000  | R010|  100   |  50  | US   \\10
  S002  | 2  | R002  | ITEM01 |  400   | R011|  100   |  50  | US   \\11
  S002  | 2  | R002  | ITEM01 |  400   | R012|  100   |  50  | US   \\12
  S002  | 2  | R002  | ITEM01 |  400   | R013|  100   |  50  | US   \\13
  S002  | 2  | R002  | ITEM01 |  400   | R014|  100   |  50  | US   \\14
```

Is there any way (Linq or looping) to get the above result? Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's no obvious link between your input and your output.  Are you expecting that the items from the `Detail` table be assigned to a record from the `Grouped` table based on a running total of the `Quantity` field?

Comment: Yes. Basically, items in source 1 & 2 are the same. But I need to remind that Shipment, Remarks and line will be assigned every 10 item with same itemcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with LINQ (which I assume you're after, since you've included the `LINQ` tag), but not in what I would consider a *nice* fashion.

Given two `DataTable` objects with the above formats and data, named **`grouped`** and **`detail`**, here's a LINQ expression that will stitch the data together in the way you want:

```
IEnumerable<object[]> qry = 
    (
        from DataRow rDetail in detail.Rows 
        let dgrp = detail.Rows.IndexOf(rDetail) / 10

        join DataRow rGroup in grouped.Rows 
            on dgrp equals grouped.Rows.IndexOf(rGroup)

        orderby rDetail["RefNo"]

        select new object[] {
                rGroup["Shipment"], rGroup["Line"], rGroup["Remarks"], rGroup["ItemCode"], rGroup["TotalQty"],
                rDetail["RefNo"], rDetail["Quantity"], rDetail["Weight"], rDetail["From"]
            }
    );
```

Now you need another `DataTable` to pump those results into:

```
DataTable res = new DataTable();
res.Columns.Add("Shipment", typeof(string));
res.Columns.Add("Line", typeof(Int32));
res.Columns.Add("Remarks", typeof(string));
res.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
res.Columns.Add("TotalQty", typeof(Int32));
res.Columns.Add("RefNo", typeof(string));
res.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(Int32));
res.Columns.Add("Weight", typeof(Int32));
res.Columns.Add("From", typeof(string));
```

And finally, fill the `res` table with the results of the LINQ query:

```
foreach (object[] rowdata in qry)
    res.Rows.Add(rowdata);
```

---

The code above works for this specific set of data, but I can't promise you anything more than that.  It is heavily dependent on the row order in the source tables, and because I'm using `DataTable.Rows.IndexOf` to get the order it's quite possible that this will be terribly slow on large collections of data.

But then you're already using `DataTable`s instead of a properly typed collection, so all bets are off in the performance- and code-sanity stakes anyway.

This is one case where I'd suggest *not* using LINQ to perform the task.  IMHO this would be better done as an iterative loop rather than a query.  You don't get much (if any) improvement over the iterative version, you lose a lot of clarity, and you have all sorts of fun getting things set up just right before you can use it.

---

And because I can't leave well-enough alone, here's a full (long, lots of code) solution using a combination of LINQ, classes to hold the data being processed and iteration to generate the table:

```
public DataTable MergeShippingData(DataTable groupTable, DataTable detailTable)
{
    // convert group table to array of GroupEntry objects
    var groupList = 
        (
            from DataRow grouprow in groupTable.Rows
            let ent = GroupEntry.FromRow(grouprow)
            where ent != null
            select ent
        ).ToArray();

    // convert detail table to sequence of DetailEntry objects
    var detailSeq = 
            from DataRow detailrow in detailTable.Rows
            let ent = DetailEntry.FromRow(detailrow)
            where ent != null
            select ent;

    // Create output DataTable
    DataTable output = CreateOutputTable();

    // Process all detail lines into shippings
    foreach (var detail in detailSeq)
    {
        // Find available shipping group for the item code with enough remaining capacity
        var grp = groupList.First (g => g.ItemCode == detail.ItemCode && g.Remainder >= detail.Quantity);
        if (grp == null)
            throw new Exception("No available shipping found for detail item...");

        // update remaining space in shipping group
        grp.Remainder -= detail.Quantity;

        // add data to output table
        output.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                grp.Shipment, grp.Line, grp.Remarks, grp.ItemCode, grp.TotalQty,
                detail.RefNo, detail.Quantity, detail.Weight, detail.From               
            });
    }

    return output;
}

// Class to hold the shipping groups while processing
public class GroupEntry
{
    // fields from source DataTable
    public string ItemCode;
    public int TotalQty;
    public string Shipment;
    public string Remarks;
    public int Line;

    // process variable, holds remaining quantity value
    public int Remainder;

    // Convert DataRow into GroupEntry
    public static GroupEntry FromRow(DataRow r)
    {
        try 
        {
            return new GroupEntry
            {
                ItemCode = r.Field<string>(0),
                TotalQty = r.Field<int>(1),
                Shipment = r.Field<string>(2),
                Remarks = r.Field<string>(3),
                Line = r.Field<int>(4),
                Remainder = r.Field<int>(1)
            };
        }
        catch { }
        return null;
    }
}

// Class to hold shipping Detail records during processing
public class DetailEntry
{
    public string RefNo;
    public string ItemCode;
    public int Quantity;
    public int Weight;
    public string From;

    // Convert DataRow into DetailEntry
    public static DetailEntry FromRow(DataRow r)
    {
        try
        {
            return new DetailEntry
            {
                RefNo = r.Field<string>(0),
                ItemCode = r.Field<string>(1),
                Quantity = r.Field<int>(2),
                Weight = r.Field<int>(3),
                From = r.Field<string>(4)
            };
        }
        catch { }
        return null;
    }
}

// Create output DataTable
public DataTable CreateOutputTable()
{
    DataTable res = new DataTable();
    res.Columns.Add("Shipment", typeof(string));
    res.Columns.Add("Line", typeof(Int32));
    res.Columns.Add("Remarks", typeof(string));
    res.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
    res.Columns.Add("TotalQty", typeof(Int32));
    res.Columns.Add("RefNo", typeof(string));
    res.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(Int32));
    res.Columns.Add("Weight", typeof(Int32));
    res.Columns.Add("From", typeof(string));

    return res;
}
```

Add some error handling and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But it's for single type of item only? Because i tried to use 2 types of itemcode (ITEM01 & ITEM02), it cannot work

Comment: Your original set of data didn't include a second item type, so I didn't know that was a condition.  At this point I'd definitely not build a LINQ statement - iterate over the records instead, outer loop for the `grouped` list, inner loop for the `detail` list.

Comment: OK, so this one bugged me enough to write a full solution.  Single loop over the detail records, handles multiple item codes, allocates details to groups based on quantity, etc.  Threw in a bunch of comments to explain.